# Connecting 25MHz crystal to STM32H7

Tags: stm32, crystal

I want to connect a 25MHz crystal to STM32H750. However, I've trouble finding a part which is suitable for use with this particular MCU.

From [AN2867](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00221665-oscillator-design-guide-for-stm8af-al-s-stm32-mcus-and-mpus-stmicroelectronics.pdf):
[image: AN2867]

In addition:

[image: AN2867]

The *gm* for STM32H750 is 1.5 mA/V ([datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32h750ib.pdf)). This means that in order to meet the recommendation, the crystal has to have *gmcrit* equal to or lower than 0.3 mA/V.

The only crystals which *come close* to this recommendation are the ones in bigger packages and with low load capacitance (The best one I've been able to find has *gmcrit* of 0.478 mA/v). So, I have few questions:

1. How much should I be worried about the *gain margin > 5* recommendation?
2. My circuit will be exposed to EMI from relays and contactors. Which parameters of a crystal are the most important for stability in this case?
3. The 25MHz crystal is not a strict requirement - I wanted to use HSE as source for the Master Clock Output for a Ethernet PHY. Should I just opt in for a lower frequency crystal and use a different source for the MCO instead?

Comment: What value of external series resistor are you considering using (see figure 5 of the datasheet you linked)? If you factored this in the Gmcrit figure becomes bigger because it adds to ESR maybe? In other words see section 3.5.3 on page 16.

Comment: I haven't considered adding any resistor yet. To my knowledge it often is redundant. But this is something I was planning to check after settling on a specific crystal. If I understand the application note correctly, adding a series resistor will increase the gmcrit of a crystal which in result will decrease the gain margin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MCO output does not depend on your crystal, so there is no real reason to want a 25 MHz crystal even if you want a 25 MHz output.

However, if the MCO output comes from a PLL, it might be a problem. This configuration was specifically not recommended on STM32F2 due to jitter.

If you really want a single 25 MHz clock source for both, why bother with a crystal, if you can buy a 25 MHz crystal oscillator module and feed the 25 MHz square wave to both devices. The problem anyway is routing 25 MHz clocks properly between the chips.

Or, it may be cheaper to get a 25 MHz crystal for the Ethernet PHY and separate crystal for STM32.

I forgot the answers:

1. Somewhat worried. Depends a bit who you ask. 3 to 5 might be acceptable or not safe. 5 to 10 is just safe or  very safe. Sometimes above 10 is very safe. ST themselves say 5 is minimum to ensure proper operation and if margin is less than 5 you should change the crystal. They know their own MCUs and their internal oscillator circuitry best.
2. I don't know if crystal parameters matter much. Crystal circuits are very sensitive so any EMI is bad. I think what affects more is proper PCB layout than any of the crystal parameters. Refer to STM32 hardware design guides for crystal layout guidelines.
3. Based on what I wrote above, likely yes.

Comment: I would prefer to go with a single crystal / crystal oscillator - Used as HSE for STM32H7 which will be used as clock source for MCO. Haven't thought about crystal oscillators. Is there a reason why crystals are seen used more often even though they're more complicated to setup (atleast it's what I'm seeing)?

Comment: @bluewheel Crystals are cheap and easy, except if you want something special and it gets tricky and difficult. Oscillators are expensive, power hungry, cause a lot of EMI with fast square wave edges and the  harmonic frequencies. Routing strongly driven square wave clock signals on PCB needs some care. They also require supply voltage, good local supply bypassing with maybe multiple capacitors, perhaps even ferrite beads for preventing EMI going up to the supply and other components. The square output might need source series termination resistors and maybe few pF loading to prevent ringing.

Comment: It looks like most of the discovery kits from ST on which Ethernet is available utilize a 25 MHz CMOS oscillator instead of a typical crystal circuit. Thanks @Justme for pointing in the right direction.